# Study of a series of functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, convergence-divergence, asymptotics, uniform-convergence

I've to study this series:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{\sqrt n\,x}$$

My teacher wrote that with the asymptotic comparison with this series:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}$$
My series converges for every

$$x<0$$

I don't understand the motivation, hoping for someone to enlighten me!

=) Thanks. Leonardo.

Comment: Something seems to be missing in what you wrote: $$e^{\sqrt n\,x}\rlap{\;\;\;\;/}\xrightarrow [n\to\infty]{} 0 $$

for $\,x>0\,$.

 It also would be a good idea if you checked in FAQ where they explain how to use LaTeX to properly write mathematics in this site.

Comment: I know that doesn't go to zero, but that's exactly what my teacher wrote. (Ps thanks for the revision)

Comment: Well, then he's wrong. Perhaps he actually wrote $\,x<0\,$?

Comment: Yes, yes, you are right, I'm going to correct! Thanks, but I don't understand again =D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may have copied the series down wrong, since $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{\sqrt{n}x}$ does not converge for $x>0$! Certainly $e^{\sqrt{n}x}$ is greater than one for any $n, x >0$ so the sum definitely diverges. I think you meant to say that it converges for $x < 0$ (or change a sign in the exponent in the sum), which is true.

To do this, we look at the power series expansion of $e^{\sqrt{n}x}$ and compare this term to $\frac{1}{n^2}$. For $x < 0$ we can write $x = - y$ where $y>0$, so $e^{\sqrt{n}x} = e^{-\sqrt{n}y}$. By looking at the fifth term in the series expansion of $e^{\sqrt{n}y}$,  which is $\frac{n^2y^4}{4!}$, we can say $e^{\sqrt{n}y} >\frac{n^2y^4}{4!}$ and hence $e^{\sqrt{n}x} = e^{-\sqrt{n}y} <\frac{4!}{n^2y^4} = \frac{4!}{n^2x^4} $. So now we can compare our original series to a constant multiple ($\frac{4!}{x^4}$) of $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$ to see that it converges!

Comment: I've copied wrong! Thanks, I like your demonstration, but I have a question, for power series expansion you mean Taylor series expansion? Because we never did the one you mentioned =) Thanks again

Comment: Yeah, the power series expansion of $e^x$ is the taylor expansion. We actually define the function $e^x$ by syaing it is equal to $\displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{x^i}{i!}$ and this then gives us that taylor expansion as being the same thing. The fifth term of this, which I mentioned in the post is $\frac{x^4}{4!}$

Comment: I've got it, I expand until fourth, so the square root can fade out and I can compare with $n^2$! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @PizziraniLeonardo Great! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

If we take $\,x<0\,$ then everything's fine, since putting $\,y=-x>0\,$ and taking $\,n\,$ big enough:

$$e^{\sqrt n\,x}<n^{-2}\Longleftrightarrow n^2<e^{\sqrt n\,y}\Longleftrightarrow 2\log n<\sqrt n\,y$$

Now you can check, for example with L'Hospital's Rule, that

$$\lim_{w\to\infty}\frac{\log w}{\sqrt w\,y}=0$$

so we're done.

Comment: My doubt is basically, why $e^{\sqrt{n}x}<n^{-2}$ ?

Comment: I just wrote it my answer! What's unclear?

Comment: You started writing $e^{\sqrt{n}x}<n^{-2}$, but why?

Comment: This is logic: $$A\Longleftrightarrow B\Longleftrightarrow C$$ means "As iff B iff C", and this is what my first line means...

Comment: You are right, thanks =)